# Dealing with transactional emails going to spam from an old domain name

Tags: email, sendgrid, spam

We got a great five-letter domain name for our web app, but we're inheriting a legacy of spam being sent from that domain. And hence, Gmail immediately dumps all transactional emails into spam. This is just a tiny problem.

We're using SendGrid to handle our transactional emails and have them white-labeled to our domain. We're not blacklisted by any services.

What can I do to overcome this spam problem?

Comment: Why the vote to close? This is a real problem, a real question, and generally relates to programming. Plus, a helpful comment with your close vote would go a *long* way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there really is that much you can do, other than making sure that your dedicated IP (Which SendGrid has probably provided for you) is continually building reputation.

One of the things I'm trying to figure out is if your domain gets flagged for spam once, is it possible to recover? I am hoping it is.

Comment: I'm hoping it's possible to recover. Someone told me (though this is pretty unverifiable unless someone here knows anyone on the Gmail team) that being marked "Not Spam" by enough Gmail users will get you out of spam. Who knows how many "enough" even is.

Comment: Apologies for the lateness of this reply, but you may want to check out these guys: http://www.spamhaus.org/ Specifically, Blacklist Removal, see if that helps you out in addition to having "Not Spam" clicked in Gmail!

Comment: The funny thing is that SendGrid's IPs aren't problematic at all. I've checked to see if they're blacklisted, but they most certainly are not. I wish there were more that could be done, since this is probably the single most costly issue I currently face.

Comment: That sucks! Maybe you could try to contact Google and see if there is a way to get whitelisted in their own system? (Though their customer service can be spotty at times, so good luck!)